# CSS Selectors - How to extract a string that doesn't belong to a tag?

Tags: css, selector

```
<div class="class1">
this is string hi hi hi
    <div class="class2">
        hi 
    </div>
</div> 

result: "this is string hi hi hi"
```

Is it possible to extract a string that does not belong to a tag using only a css selector? Content in class2 should be excluded.

Comment: if you want to hide `.class2` content you can do it by setting it's display to none,`.class2{display: none} `

Comment: It's crawling. I want to extract using a selector without touching the document.

Comment: If you want to extract string and use with something else, then use JavaScript. CSS can show or hide string that is displaying to the web browser. Or if you running it on server side and PHP supported, maybe use PHP `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good way to put raw text in `div` in this situation.
I recommand you to put `span` or other inline tags and then put your string in it, then the problem will get much easier.

If you want to extract only string in this situation, you can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

```js
const class1 = document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0]
const class2 = document.getElementsByClassName('class2')[0]
const text1 = class1.textContent
const text2 = class2.textContent
console.log(text1.substr(0, text1.lastIndexOf(text2)))
```

```html
<div class="class1">
this is string hi hi hi
    <div class="class2">
        hi 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm crawling a bad site. The tag contains raw text, is it difficult to extract it using only selectors?

Comment: class2 content is also considered as content of class1 so you need to fabricate it

Comment: you are right. thank you for your kindness

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution. You need to touch the document, but it won't affect the document actually because what I do here will be done in backend.

```
let newElementStr = class1.innerHTML;//Get the content of Class 1 including Class 2
//Create a duplicate of Class 1 Element and hide it.
let newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.style.display = 'none';
newElement.innerHTML = newElementStr;
newElement.id = 'new-el';
//Remove the Class 2 Element
let class2Element = document.querySelector('#new-el .class2');
document.remove(class2Element);
let content = newElement.innerHTML;//This is the string you want
document.remove(newElement);//Cleaning up
```

You don't need to worry about touching the document because all the changes made by this code won't affect the document because they are hidden `display: none;`

Hope it works for you!

Comment: thank you. Many things have been solved thanks to you.